# Plotting in R missing indices in x plot

Tags: r

I am drawing a plot in R as follow:

```
 respCSV=read.csv("R1.csv")
 respCol=respCSV[["RESP"]]
 plot(respCol,type='o')
```

when it plot the series, the x axis lable are not countinuous, instead of 1,2,3,4,
it is 1,5,10.how to fix that?

Comment: you need to show your data

Comment: it is confidentioal

Comment: You need to make up fake data and follow the instructions for making a minimal reproducable example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the issue is that the *axis labels* are too spare, and your x variable is continuous you can make your own.  This works on standard calls to `plot` and sometimes it works on plots based on it, but not always.

```
plot(x, y, xaxt = 'n') # get rid of the default x-axis
axis(1, at = 1:10, values = 1:10) # put the values you want.
```

Note that there may be other reasons why your axis labels aren't showing up.  If the x-axis isn't continuous, the solution will be different.